# PHP : Insert/Append to file is faster or MySQL insert is faster?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I want to make 100 string inserts separately (not bulk or mass insert , 1 by 1)

Example input string:

```
col1,col2,col3,col4
```

With each request to server I will get that input. Lets say I will get a total of 100 requests.
In each request I need to store the input string.

so I do

```
<?php
file_put_contents("filename", $_GET['string']),FILE_APPEND, LOCK_EX);
?>
```

or I should do

```
<?php
$handle = mysqli_connect([params]);
$handle->query("INSERT into table (string) values (string)");
$handle->close();
?>
```

I don't know how to find this out. Because I can't make 100 requests.
But if anyone knows this already or can help let me know.

What should I do? File or Mysql

And also what if the requests are 100000+ , I would like to know for both cases, 100 requests as well as 100000+.

Comment: This question is way to vague to give advise. What are you trying to accomplish? What lenghts of string will you be writing? What will happen with the data once its written?

Comment: Well to answer your title question writing to a file is faster. But I agree with @j4k3

Comment: Writing to a file may be faster as a one-off, but what are you doing with the information subsequently? Do you need to access it via the type of queries that a database can provide? Or is it simply "log" type information that will rarely be accessed subsequently, and that can be filtered if necessary using grep or other filesystem tools?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining well, well I just need to store. I am not going to use them. Its logs. And I mentioned the example string, its same format like that, so max chars would be less than 100-200 in the string.